# how to load multiple files from directory into an array using matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have a directory that includes some .mat files , i want to load all these files into an array .
i tried something like this :;

```
x1=load('C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\project\a\first_file.mat')
x2=load('C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\project\a\second_file.mat')
```

... and so on for all the files in the directory , and at the end i want to have an array such that:

```
arr(1)=x1 ...
```

how can i access the directory and load all of the files at the same time into an array ?

ps: i tried using path before and dir but then i got this error :

> error using eval , undefind function 'workspacefun' for input
> arguments of type struct

thank you in advance.

Comment: loading .mat files normally loads them into your workspace. there, the data will be loaded, but with a different name (only you can see what the name of the data in the workspace is). then, you can use `arr(1) = DATA_1; arr(2) = DATA2; ...`

Comment: note that if the data stored in the mat files has the same variable name, you will have to load the first one, then add that to the array, then load the second one, add it to the array, load the 3rd, add it (instead of loading them all and then adding them all).

Comment: When `load` is used with an output variable, it returns a struct containing a field for each variable in the .mat file. We would have to know what your .mat file contains in order to help you, but in general, you'd do it by concatenating `x1.variable_name` to your result array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` function loads what variables are in the `.mat` file with their real names into the current workspace. If you assign `x` as an output for `load`, the variables names appear as fields of a struct named `x`. For example, if `first.mat` contains `v1`, then, `x = load('first.mat')` will result in a `x = struct with fields: v1`.

So, in your case, assuming that you are sure that each `.mat` file contains a single variable, you can write the following loop to load all `.mat` files into a cell array `arr`.

```
fds = fileDatastore('*.mat', 'ReadFcn', @load);  % assume same folder
files = fds.Files;
for i = 1:length(files)
    % convert one-field struct into array, store in "arr"
    arr{i} = struct2array(load(files{i}));
end
```

And each `arr{i}` will now contain a variable, say `vi`, in lexicographic order. If the `.mat` file contains more than one variable, this code will break. If the files are in another folder, you can use their actual `path` and extension like this `fileDatastore('path', 'ReadFcn', @load, 'FileExtensions','.mat')`.